# JavaScript - access network tab via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, console

I need to access the (for example) Chrome Developer Tools network tab with **JavaScript**. I only need

1.) Source Name (column 1) and
2.) Type (column 3)

But I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Links are very apprecciated!

[image: Example - Chrome Developer Tools]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made some research, but it seems like **you can't do it**, you can't access the devtools directly from js, but from what I have read you could use `console.profile()` as follow:

```
console.profile()
console.profileEnd()
```

But it seems it does not return the value of the profile, its accessible from the devTools... not ideal...

But you could use **PhantomJS** or something similar, dont know if would accomplish wwat you are after...

Or check this google group discussion about the topic:

- [Programmatic access to network panel entries through console / javascript](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/beDuY1DGZRA)

Comment: Thank you!https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network is what i'm looking for... but are there also ways for.. lets say firefox or IE/Edge?

Comment: I've seen this for firefox... although it says its Obsolete, but hope it helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI dont know if there is any way to do it in IE/Edge