# Access html response payload in chrome console

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the 'successURL' element of a response payload in chrome console, but cannot work it out. I've tried everything I can think of --> payload.successUrl, e.payload.successUrl, data.payload, but can't seem to access the element.

Anyone able to help? Thanks!

[image: Response payload in chrome tools]

Comment: how did you end up having this object in the first place? could you provide more info, like a function that produces the object, or where it comes from, or how you are trying to get those values?

Comment: Thanks Tch - that question (along with webdev-dans) helped me answer my question. I need to parse the response before I send it to the console. Duh. Simple, rookie error.  I'll update my question so it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

As you shown on image attached to your question - you have successfully accessed this in chrome console :)
You can now right-click to see context-menu and copy it to a variable or do some other things.

But If what you mean is to access data from developer tools straight away in a script - it's rather impossible.
For more information on that - read this aswered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571792/3054380

If the request resulting with that payload data was made by your script - then you need to show how you did this - and surely it is quite simple to access any data recieved in response.

Comment: Thank you webdev-dan. You've saved me a lot of time messing around when the answer was at my fingertips. I'm pretty rusty at development. I'm including the answer to my question in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in my question from webdev-dan and Tch (I can't upvote them as I don't have the reputation, sorry!). I was trying to access the response after it was posted to console as opposed to parsing the data in my script then sending to console.

Here is what I did to get the element from the response I needed (successUrl).

Javascript

```
  const result = await frui.getSession();

  console.log(result);
  console.log(result.payload);
  console.log(result.payload.successUrl);
```

Response in console

[image: Response in console]

I'll now set the result.payload.successUrl as a variable to use later on.