# How to get Network request call stack using any tool

Tags: google-chrome

In a chrome dev tool, you can see the call stack for the script-initiated network request. Is there any way I can capture it programmatically?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571529/javascript-access-network-tab-via-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)